# What are the advantages of using ellipsometry over AFM to determine film thickness?

Tags: spectroscopy, materials

I am trying to understand why one would chose one over the other and I am struggling to understand this since both are non destructive. I know AFM can only go at 5 nm but other than that I don't see anything.

I am also struggling to wrap my head around the concept of ellipsometry so any suggestions or insights into how this technique works would be amazing.